# Doubt on connectedness of Mandelbrot Sets

Tags: complex-analysis

I am taking a Coursera course on [Complex analysis](https://class.coursera.org/complexanalysis-001). In a lecture introducing Mandelbrot set, the following example was given:

1. Choose a window $W = {c_x + ic_y : c_{xmin} ≤ c_x ≤ c_{xmax} , c_{ymin} ≤ c_y ≤ c_{ymax} }$ to display. If you want to see the entire Mandelbrot set, you’d want something like $W = {c : −2 ≤ c_x ≤ 0.75, −1.5 ≤ c_y ≤ 1.5}$.
2. As before, pick a largest number of iterations, maxiter. The larger this number, the more accurate your picture will get, but the slower the calculation will be.
3. For each pixel on your screen, choose a parameter c in your window W, corresponding to that pixel. We’ll look at the corresponding polynomial $f(z) = z^2+ c$.
4. Calculate the iterates of 0 under this polynomial:
   $f(0) = c, f(f(0)) = c^2+ c, f(f(f(0))) = (c^2+ c)^2+ c,$ . . . If one of these iterates satisﬁes that $|f^n(0)| > 2$, color the initial pixel white.
5. If you reach the maximum number of iterations, maxiter, without having left $B_2(0)$, there’s a good chance that the parameter c belongs to the Mandelbrot set M. Color this pixel black.

Now, the video shows the example Mandelbrot set and zooms into the boundary. Here, the third zoom shows a black zone that is disconnected from the main set.

Moreover, more such "disconnected" black zones appear in higher zoom-ins.

Zoom 1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByF1LTgjPSsvRmhHT3FSaWEwYzA/edit?usp=sharing

Zoom 2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByF1LTgjPSsvYXJSUEh4c0lvOHc/edit?usp=sharing

Zoom 3: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByF1LTgjPSsvQkp2bWNmVDNJUW8/edit?usp=sharing

How can a Mandelbrot set have disconnected parts ? What is going on there ?

The coursera course is closed. So I thought I would ask my doubt here.

EDIT: This is associated with the Big Open Conjecture in the ﬁeld of complex dynamics:

The Mandelbrot set is locally connected, that is, for every c ∈ M and every open
set V with c ∈ V, there exists an open set U such that c ∈ U ⊂ V and U ∩ M is
connected.

This is NOT proved yet !

Comment: How do I insert images from my PC here ?

Comment: The Mandelbrot set is definitely connected. Chances are you are seeing a piece that is connected to a larger bulb by a very fine filament that isn't visible in your rendering. There is also the possibility of rounding error or truncation error (not enough iterations to detect escape to infinity). Both of these become more influential as you approach the boundary of the set.